# .text() function does not show HTML tags like I want. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to limit 300 charecters to show in a container and using this

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.shippingMessage').append($('#forQuickViewOnly'));
        var myDiv = $('#firstPara');
        myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0, 300));
        $('.productdetailtopquickview .productdetailshopnowform').appendTo($('.infoHolder'));
    });
</script>
```

**I am trying to show `<ul><li><li></ul>` structure but i am getting a paragraph.** In other words, the list formatting is getting stripped. Any idea how to prevent that?

Comment: if you use `.text()` you will only get text. If you want to keep the HTML you need to use `.html()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: now i am seeing line breaks but I am not seeing the bullets. Do i have to add anything?

Comment: @soum Inspect the code and see what CSS styles are applied to it. Also check if the HTML markup is still intact and valid.

Comment: Update your question with the HTML. Include all the divs you reference in the JS.

Comment: @andrew- problem solved. There is a saying never rush to solve a problem and thats what I was doing. I just had to assign list-style:circle. Thanks for the direction man

Comment: @sachleen- there is no change in the question.